# Software projects for space systems

Tags: software

I am a software engineer with a strong grasp of python. I want to branch out and start working for space startups after I read there was a shortage of good software engineers working in the burgeoning industry.

Before that I want to start getting some experience in the different kinds of applications they are building, so I’m looking for resources like this. Open source projects, courses, technical specs, honestly anything that might help point me in the right direction.

Anyone have any good resources?

Comment: Kudos for your enthusiasm! Your question asking for "...honestly anything that might help point me in the right direction." is too broad for a Stack Exchange question, it's also what is called a "list question" (the answer can be an arbitrarily long list), answers can be primarily opinion-based, and there can be no correct answer. So while it is potentially a good question for some forum, it is a bad question for Stack Exchange, and if you don't edit it it will probably be quickly closed.

Comment: Can you focus on something specific that you would like to ask, something that can have a fact-based, objective, and correct answer? Have you tried simply searching for open source projects relating to space? If you found some interesting results, you could ask further questions about one here. You can also search this site for the term open source.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and can understand wanting to avoid the the arbitrarily long list answer, I honestly don't have anything specific in mind yet but will do some research today and then post back with an edit.

Comment: Depending what you would like to do with "space systems". Satellite embedded software developers use C/C++, and normally require good knowledge of linux/makefiles, some people also use VHDL. Python is sometimes used for test automation. Some software for ground stations have web-based front-ends, and use databases for storing and working with telemetry.

Comment: But the best advice I can give you is: Look for jobs in the areas you are interested in. Read carefully their requirements and, over time, some names will pop up more than others.

Comment: How about reframing the question into something like "what are the applications for the Python language in the space industry"? That's probably still broad, but something that could be answered with citations at least.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a note - I took the advice in the comments (thanks to @uhoh and @Mefitico) and did a little research onto this outside of SE, since posting a very broad question can lead to long winded and listed answers.

Found a couple of great resources, but [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/976/is-the-software-running-on-any-existing-or-decommissioned-space-probes-available?rq=1) actually gave me pretty much exactly what I was looking for, in case anyone comes across this question with the same sort of questions.